# import NLTK doesn't work with Hadoop Streaming

Tags: hadoop, nltk, hadoop2, hadoop-streaming, wordnet

I want to use the nltk data in my mapreduce program, but when I import the nltk and use a function from it , it failed .

I read in some forum that I need to import all the nltk to the remote task nodes or something like that ?

Can anyone please suggest me a solution to run the nltk functions in my mapreduce program

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
 nltk.data.path.append("/home/uname/nltk_data/")
```

you can try to use the codes above to specify the path where NLTK will search the data.

Comment: I'm revising your answer: you can improve it by adding some extra info to make it more interesting for future users